# Redis - How to store the result of zrange query as another ordered set

Tags: redis, sortedset

For example I create a sorted set with this command:

```
zadd key1 1 u1 2 u2 3 u3
```

Now I to query last 2 items and store under other key, say `key2`. I know that I need to query like this:

```
zrange key1 -2 -1
```

but I don't know how to store the result with `key2`. Sorry for noob question, I am new to Redis, just 2 hours :)

Answer (score 3):

While Redis does not have a built-in command to do that, you can get away easily and safely with a Lua script. This one is a just a little extra tricky because the reply from ZRANGE needs swapping between the pairs of member-score to be used as input for ZADD.

```
local src, dst = KEYS[1], KEYS[2]
local from, to = ARGV[1], ARGV[2]

local payload = redis.call('ZRANGE', src, from, to, 'WITHSCORES')

for i = 1, #payload/2 do
  payload[2*i-1], payload[2*i] = payload[2*i], payload[2*i-1]
end

return redis.call('ZADD', dst, unpack(payload))
```

For details on how to use Lua in Redis see the [`EVAL` commmand](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Answer (score 0):

ZRANGESTORE was added to Redis 6.2